# Translation in Happyx

Tags: web, http-headers, translation, nim-lang

Can I translate strings in happyx web framework?

For example

```
...
get "/":
  if lang == "en":
    return "Hello, world!"
  else:
    return "Bye"
```

Now I'm trying to use request headers to detect language, but can I made it otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **translatable strings** that available since [v1.5.0](https://github.com/HapticX/happyx/releases/tag/v1.5.0)

Here is example

```
# Declare your translatable strings
translatable:
  "Hello, world!":  # this string will be used by default
    "ru" -> "Привет"
    "jp" -> "こんにちは"

...

  get "/":
    # In SSR/SSG, language takes from HTTP headers
    # In SPA, language takes from browser
    return translate("Hello, world!")
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `prologue/i18n` module you can load translations from translation catalogues.

There is the [i18n example application](https://github.com/planety/prologue-examples/tree/master/i18n) in the prologue examples repository, which demonstrates how to switch translations based on URL query parameters.

It boils down to these steps:

1. Set the available languages in the application settings:

```
settings = newSettings(..., data = %* {"languages": languages}
```

2. Load the translation catalogue:

```
app.loadTranslate(expandFileName("translations/trans.ini"))
```

3. In the views, retrieve the available languages from the `Context` and the selected translation from the query params:

```
languages = ctx.gScope.settings["languages"].getElems().mapIt(it.getStr())
lang = ctx.request.queryParams.getOrDefault("lang", "en")
```

4. Use `translate(ctx: Context, text: string, language: string)` to translate your strings:

```
ctx.translate("Hello World!", lang)
```

I guess it would be relatively easy to either get the language from the HTTP headers instead directly in the views or use a custom middleware to set it in the context for every view.

Comment: No, I don't need prologue